# Remove directory content Web dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

I am creating a local web application where I want to be able to clear the content of my directory.

How can I remove the files from a directory without deleting the directory itself?
I need it to be empty.

Is it better to remove the whole dir and create it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting the files of your local system you need a server-side scripting language. Vanilla Js cannot do that for you as it is a client-side scripting language.

If you are using **Nodejs**, as it is a server side you can definitely do that using `unlink()` for deleting file **asynchronously** or use `unlinkSync()` for deleting file **synchronously** you can learn about how to use that function [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/delete-a-file-in-nodejs-using-node-fs/)...

Demo code `unlinkSync()` -

```
const fs = require('fs');

let filename = "D:\\temp\\temp.zip";    
fs.unlinkSync(filename);
```

Comment: I do not have a server. It is all local on an offline device

Comment: You can create a local `devserver` using Nodejs. You can watch a video here to how to setup a local server in Nodejs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnPemSnnJYY

Answer (score 2):

If javascript can delete directory contents, that would a pretty big security concern. Javascript by itself cannot delete system contents. You can make an AJAX call to the server which in turn can delete the files